# Using an excel membership number list to compile a civi report of linked addresses

Tags: civimember, civireport, groups

I have a list of membership numbers of approx 80 people. I need to use these numbers (saved in an excel spreadsheet) to run a report in Civi which will pull all the addresses and names linked to those numbers (with the number) into a new excel sheet which I will then use for a mail merge.

When in Civi I can see that you can import a spreadsheet but that seems to be to add new members. What I need is not to add memberships/individuals but to use the numbers to collate information linked to those numbers already in Civi.

Can anybody help with the best way to do this without adding any duplicate information to Civi, or manually typing/searching all 80 people?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by numbers, do you mean a unique ID or a phone number? Also, it generally helps to tell us what version of CiviCRM and what CMS (Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress) you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If the "membership number" corresponds to the CiviCRM Contact ID, or to the External Identifier field, you can use **Contacts menu » Import Contacts** to import JUST the membership number.  On the final field of the import, use the option to create a new Group of the imported records.  Since all of the corresponding members exist in CiviCRM, this won't do anything except add everyone in your spreadsheet to the group.

Then you can do a Search for that Group, then do an export of the required fields.

Comment: thx jon for expanding on my brevity

Comment: Thank you - this is extremely helpful! Yes the membership number is the Civi ID so this is perfect.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi. I have just tried this and encountered a syntax error. The membership number is its own identifying column under Civi ID not as I first thought. When selecting a relevant column to match the data with there isn't membership number as an option and the only similar possibility is 'Internal Contact ID'. I tried this and got a syntax error message and the group has been created but with no contacts. I am not sure how otherwise to categorize this unique number in the import 'Matching Civi CRM field. 'External Identifier' threw an error message before import. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Do an export of all Internal IDs and your Membership number, then use a formula called a vlookup to add the Internal ID to your list of numbers that you want to import, then run the import with the Internal ID